# The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following scenario, How can i do this without getting the System.InvalidOperationException error.

SomeClass.cs:

```
using (var eo = new MyEntities())
{
   targetRole = (from p in eo.UserRoles 
                 where p.Code == 2 
                 select p).FirstOrDefault();
}

var user = new User
{
   UserName = userName,
   Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim(),
   UserRole = targetRole
};

AnotherClass.AddObject(user);
```

AnotherClass.cs

```
public static void AddObject(object poco)
{
    using (var eo = new MyEntities())
    {
        eo.AddObject("Users", poco);
        eo.SaveChanges();  //<--- Exceptions Thrown.
    }
}
```

Comment: Well where is the error thrown, what line?

Comment: Is `User` your own type or EF generated?

Comment: It's an EF generated entity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself, I need to attach the targetRole object to the current context:

AnotherClass.cs :

```
public static void AddObject(object poco)
{
   using (var eo = new MyEntities())
   {
       eo.UserRoles.Attach(targetRole); //<-- the magic
       eo.AddObject("Users", poco);
       eo.SaveChanges();  //<--- it works like a charm. Hoorah
   }
}
```